# Best practices to manage versions with scons?

Tags: c++, qt, scons

I would like my Qt/C++ application to know which version it is. It should know that not from some configuration files, but with version number compiled into application binary. A version itself is string like "X.Y.Z", where X is a major version number, Y is a minor version number and Z is a revision under SVN (or a revision number under SVN minus a revision number when version "X.Y.0" came out). What would you think is the simplest way to accomplish this with scons?

Comment: If the only purpose of the version number is to display something to the user, a string is OK. If there's any programmatic access, you will want to have each of the version components in a separate field (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2195573/why-use-a-nested-ruby-module-for-version-information/2195824#2195824). Also to make it easy to automate version increments (e.g. for a release build script), separating the version into fields is a win.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

SCons has `Substfile` and `Textfile` builders for generating files. So create a function to calculate the version (using [pysvn](http://pysvn.tigris.org/) or by calling `svn` command) and write it's output to a file using `Substfile` (takes template from a file) or `Textfile` (just writes provided content). Than compile and link that file with the rest of the application.

The file should be a source file (*not* a header) with content like (assuming C/C++, but the same technique would be appropriate with any language):

```
char *VERSION = "X.Y.Z";
```

(and any other alternate formats you want) and declare

```
extern char *VERSION;
```

somewhere, than only the one file will be recompiled plus the application relinked (which it will anyway, because some other sources probably changed too, right).

Comment: +1. Putting the version values in a source file is a good idea. I find it useful to make a header (that doesn't need to be modified) with accessor functions for 1. the version string, and 2. a version structure with separate fields for major, minor, etc. values.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll go with this one. Sorry for being so slow to accept.

Comment: this is very helpful, but I think that the part of how to calculate/retrieve the version is missing. Per OP, Z can be calculated from svn, but where do X.Y come from? I guess they should be somehow in the branch/tag name?

Answer (score 1):

Here are some more answers that came from [scons-users] mailing list.

**Brian Cody:**

> One command line option we pass into
>   scons is the repository version of the
>   SVN rep. We then put this number into
>   a define (-DREP_NUM=\"123\") and build
>   a string in our C++ code that uses
>   this number. That's for our server run
>   builds. For local builds, we actually
>   use the username instead of the
>   version number, because someone's
>   local build of version XYZ doesn't
>   necessarily equal someone else's XYZ
>   (in windows, the env var USERNAME
>   contains the logged-in user). One
>   other consideration is that changing
>   any part of a compilation statement in
>   scons means that the target is
>   automatically out-of-date. To work
>   around this issue our build system
>   picks out the one object target that
>   actually cares about the flags and it
>   only passes the flags to the
>   compilation of that one object.
>
> Good luck

**Gary Oberbrunner:**

> > I would like my Qt/C++ application to know which version it is.
>
> There's some info at
>   http://www.scons.org/wiki/BuildNumberProcessing
>   which may be helpful.
>
> -- 
>   -- Gary